# Texlive 2021: tlmgr

Tags: package-management, upgrade, latex, paths, texlive

I have installed Texlive 2021 on Ubuntu 21.04 on a new laptop. There aren't previous version of Texlive in the system.
I have had to install it as root user since, while trying to install it as simple user he didn't let the installer write in some directories.

Following, the guide I have updated the paths in the `$HOME/.profile` file adding the following expressions:

```
if [ -d "/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
    fi
if [ -d "/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man" ] ; then
    MANPATH="/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH"
    fi
 if [ -d "/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info" ] ; then
    INFOPATH="/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH"
    fi
```

This way Latex works fine.
As for `tlmgr`, in root mode, I can open and operate the GUI.
I tried, still in root mode (in user mode ir says I have to run it in root mode)

> ```
> tlmgr update --self (and > tlmgr update --self)
> ```

It gave me the following message:

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)
TLPDB: not a directory, not loading: /root/texmf
tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!
```

I tried to employ `--usermode` and `--usertree` with no success.
Finally I wrote

> `PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; export PATH MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; export MANPATH`
> `INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH; > export INFOPATH`

This way it works.
Any alternative, that saves me copying and pasting those instruction?
When writing

```
echo $PATH
echo $MANPATH
echo $INFOPATH
```

the terminal lists the corrects directories.
What's missing?
I think I should set a PATH, but where?

**UPDATE! (partially solved but not quite)**

I copied the $PATH, $MANPATH, $INFOPATH on the .basch file.
Now

> tlmgr update -all

works fine
Unfortunately

> tlmgr update --self

responds this way.

> tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2020) is older than remote repository (2021).
> Cross release updates are only supported with
> update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
> See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.

I have tried to follow the suggestions on the upgrade page of tug.org/texlive without success.

Any idea?

Comment: This all is great. But what is your Ubuntu version? What was wrong with [texlive](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=texlive) from the official repositories? Why do you complicate APT things? Why do you really think you need 2021 version?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 21.04. Why texlive 2021? Well I'm configuring my new laptop and took it from ww.tug.org.

Comment: If I were you, I install 20.04 LTS with its 4 remaning years of support and then install `texlive-full` package here. But, ok, let's wait for solutions for your currently chosen path.

Comment: I've added an update, but the error message is weird, I don't have a a 2020 version installed in the system. I'll wait, but you know? I still can use Latex this way, it seems (I've tried to compile a couple of documents).

Comment: One of the easiest way to install the latest version of texlive is to use a user-friendly rolling release distribution. It is a good idea not to mess up with the default packages of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

TexLive ecosystem is very mature, so having latest 2021 version is not really needed on real life situations. Personally I find the usage of binary TeXLive distribution from tug.org/texlive non-reproducible and too windows-way. I would recommend to remove it.

Reallly I would recommend two things to do on fresh laptop:

1. Run a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to have bright future for next 4 years. This version is LTS - long-term support (5 years of support starting from 2020 April), so you should not run unnecessary distribution upgrades in each 9-months frames as it will with 21.04.
2. Install TeXLive 2019 from [official Ubuntu repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/focal/texlive-base) as simple as

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository universe
   sudo apt-get install texlive-full
   ```

   You should imagine the situation when your other systems exist. For example - home laptop and workstation at work. Installation of deb-packages is always reproducible and straight-forward procedure with 100% success.

Comment: Well,thanks. I tried to get creative and experiment. I've Ubuntu 20.04 with texlive 2019 in my office, at University, and wanted a change, just for the sake of it (fun?).  I don't really need much more than basic Latex packages. I actually would have liked to install stable Debian but, apparently there were some problems with a few functions.

Comment: I partly disagree... Having to wait two years for a new LTS release is a bit long, specially if you want to or need to use new features or packages, even more so when TeXLive = LTS - 1 (22.04 will be shipped with 2021).

Comment: @vitaminace33 I agree with the feeling of your point, but if you want up-to-date software then Ubuntu is not the right distro. Ubuntu is structured around twice-yearly releases, and what you're looking for is more applicable to rolling-release distributions (Debian unstable releases, Arch, etc).

Comment: @éclairevoyant You are absolutely right about Ubuntu LTS not being cutting edge, but this is no exactly what I wanted to point out. What I want to stress is that Ubuntu LTS releases, although at release time are shipped with TeXLive = LTS -1 due to a too short time window, they could easily upgrade TeXLive at LTS.1 or LTS.3. TeXLive is not cutting edge material and 6 month is more than enough to make sure that everything is stable.

Comment: @vitaminace33 Fair enough. I'm not familiar enough with their internal policies to know why they don't upgrade texlive for the whole lifespan of the LTS release